# What is the proper way to launch app using alarm manager?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to implement a flutter alarm app that opens through the alarm manager.
It seems that there is the way to do it using android_intent and android_alarm_manager_plus.
I was looking for the right way to create such functionality, but this option does not work:

```
await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      Duration(seconds: 2), 1, setAlarm);
```

```
void setAlarm()async{
  AndroidIntent intent =
      AndroidIntent(action: 'action_view', package: 'com.example.test_alarm');
  await intent.launch().catchError((e) {
    print(e.toString());
  });
}
```

Debug console gives this:

```
I/IntentSender( 4886): Cannot resolve explicit intent - ignoring package
V/IntentSender( 4886): Sending intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW (has extras) }
```

Answer (score 2):

try using https://pub.dev/packages/app_launcher

```
void setAlarm() async{
await AppLauncher.openApp(
  androidApplicationId: "com.example.test_alarm",
);
```

}

Comment: I can open any app with this function except mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is not working because the `setAlarm()` function will be run from Dart Background Isolate. So you need to modify the `AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java` code of plugin like below.

```java
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)
      context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
      PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
      PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "AlarmBroadcastReceiver:My wakelock");

    Intent startIntent = context
      .getPackageManager()
      .getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());

    if (startIntent != null)
      startIntent.setFlags(
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT |
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
      );

    wakeLock.acquire(3 * 60 * 1000L /*3 minutes*/);
    context.startActivity(startIntent);
    AlarmService.enqueueAlarmProcessing(context, intent);
    wakeLock.release();
  }
}
```

If you want to launch your app on a lock screen, need to add codes at the `MainActivity`. Here is an example code.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...

        turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff()
    }

    private fun turnScreenOnAndKeyguardOff() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON)
        } else {
            window.addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED    // deprecated api 27
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD     // deprecated api 26
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON   // deprecated api 27
                        or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
            )
        }
        val keyguardMgr = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            keyguardMgr.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
        }
    }
}
```